# Change display of buttons on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've two button like this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="entry" data-type="manual" class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Manual entry</button>

<button type="button" data-toggle="entry" data-type="auto" class="pull-right btn btn-default btn-sm hide"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Automatic entry</button>
```

On click on one of these button, I want to show the other one.

So my code is the following, but it doesn't work:

```
$("button[data-toggle='entry']").on('click', function() {

    var active = $(this).data('type');

    if(active == 'auto') {
        $("button[data-type='auto']").removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        $("button[data-type='manual']").removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
    if(active == 'manual') {
        $("button[data-type='manual']").removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        $("button[data-type='auto']").removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Why ?

https://jsfiddle.net/bry35xne/

Comment: Probably because when the "auto" button is clicked, you show the auto button and hide the manual button instead of the other way around.

Comment: `.attr("data-type")` is how you get the 'data-type' attribute

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky since JQuery 3, `.data()` has conformed to the data set usage, so this is fine

Comment: Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/bry35xne/11/